# Hibernate subquery on manytomany join column not working as expected

Tags: javascript, hibernate, hql

So I've got a pretty simple schema and I'm trying to select * articles to whom the user is following.

1. User

User can follow other users

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="userId")
private int userId;
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "user_followers",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "following_id")})
    private Set<User> following = new HashSet<User>();
```

2. Article

An article holds article info + a ***ManyToOne*** user field:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="entry")
public class Article implements Serializable {
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private User userId;

@Column(name="articleInfo")
private String articleInfo
```

This is the query I'm trying to run to select * articles -> Now this query will only select articles that the particular `:user` has made (the user whos requesting the data).

```
Query q = sess.createQuery("from Article a where a.userId IN (from a.userId.following uf where uf.userId " +
                "= :user)");

q.setParameter("user", u.getUserId());
```

But when I try and select only the uf.followingId it throws an exception saying it the field followingId doesn't exist?! As seen here ->

```
{@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "following_id")})
```

You can see that is has the ***user_id*** (user who is following -> following_id) and ***follower_id*** (user who is being followed).

I don't understand why ***I can*** do `uf.userId` ***and not***  `uf.followingId` (I've tried uf.following_id too).

```
 Query q = sess.createQuery("from Article a where a.userId IN (select uf.followingId from a.userId.following uf where uf.userId " +
                    "= :user)");
q.setParameter("user", u.getUserId());
```

Throws the following error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: followingId of: com.spring.models.db.user.User
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "user_followers",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "following_id")})
    private Set<User> following = new HashSet<User>();
```

IN above code as I can see that you are using HQL and the property "following" is a set which belongs to an intermediate table. It is neither  a direct variable of Entity User nor foreign key. That's why you are getting above exception. In HQL you will have to fire join query explicitly to get detail from JoinTable.